# Kannel HTTP POST fails

Tags: node.js, kannel

This is my NodeJS (`request-promise`) for sending SMS via `HTTP GET` with SMS gateway `Kannel`:

```
var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:13002/cgi-bin/sendsms',
    qs: {
        username: 'foo',
        password: 'bar',
        to: '127883327304',
        from: '12488331359',
        text: 'Hi
    } 
};
```

This works, but changing to `HTTP POST` fails.

```
var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:13002/cgi-bin/sendsms',
    form: {
        username: 'foo',
        password: 'bar',
        to: '127883327304',
        from: '12488331359',
        text: 'Hi
    } 
 };
```

Getting `body: 'Authorization failed for sendsms' } }`

Also able to get: `body: 'Invalid content-type' } }`

But the content-type is correct http form: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

...and tried old school XML:

```
var xml = ' \
<?xml version="1.0"?>\
<message>\
  <submit>\
    <da><number>11021034235</number></da>\
    <oa><number>11076034723</number></oa>\
    <ud>Hello</ud>\
    <from>\
      <user>foo</user>\
      <username>foo</username>\
      <pass>bar</pass>\
      <password>bar</password>\
    </from>\
  </submit>\
</message>\
';
var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:13002/cgi-bin/sendsms',
  body: xml,
  headers: {'content-type': 'text/xml'}
};
```

but getting: `body: 'Authorization failed for sendsms' } }`

I'm lost on what to do, and HTTP GET doesn't work for long SMSes.

Comment: Have you tried passing `username` and `password` in the query string and the rest with `form`?

Comment: How should we answer your question without knowing about your backend's auth strategy?

Comment: Sorry, I'm running Kannel.org.

Comment: Adding username and password to query URL doesn't change anything :(

Comment: Looking through all examples in Kannel's contrib-folder all uses HTTP GET, which fails for long SMSes.

Comment: Seems Kannel actually doesn't support HTTP POST for sending SMSes, which is a limit for long SMSes :( Hope to be proved wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Tried

```
request({
url: 'http://127.0.0.1:13002/cgi-bin/sendota',
method: 'POST',
headers : {
    'content-type': 'text/xml',
    'X-Kannel-Username': 'foo',
    'X-Kannel-Password': 'bar',
    'X-Kannel-To': '1324422133',
    'X-Kannel-From': '12023455750'
},
body: xml
}, function (error, response, body) {
console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
});
```

Now I'm getting body: Unsupported content-type, rejected
but text/xml should be supported...